# Equivilent of "npm install" for gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependency-management

I'm (re)starting to learn Ruby and am writing an application which will (unsurprisingly) require several gems to be installed. I'll need to provide this application to someone else to run, and I'm concerned that they won't have the gems needed. Coming from node.js, with it's package.json and ability to "npm install", leaves me wondering how to ensure dependencies will be easy for others to install. I can include a shell script to install everything, but is there a better, more Rubyish way to do manage gems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An excellent tool for dependency management in Ruby projects is [Bundler](http://bundler.io/). It allows Ruby projects to specify the exact gems and versions required for the app to run as intended.

You can specify the dependencies within a Gemfile in the root of your directory, like so:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'rack', '~>1.1'
gem 'rspec', :require => 'spec'
```

If the end user has bundler available on their system, they can run `bundle install` within your app and have all the necessary gems installed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Bundler is what I generally use.It has functionalities that match that of npm.For example if I have dependancies inside the `Gemfile` itself bundler will automatically take care of them and create the `Gemfile.lock` for you. Do have a look [here.](http://bundler.io/)

Answer (score -1):

The Ruby equivalent to `npm` is a project called [*RubyGems*](http://guides.rubygems.org/), the equivalent to `npm install` is [`gem install`](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-install). [Dependencies](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#add_runtime_dependency) are listed in the [Gemspec](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/) and typically installed automatically.